# How should this equation be read, $|z+1+3i|=|z-5-7i|$

Tags: complex-numbers, notation

$$|z+1+3i|=|z-5-7i|$$
$z$ represents a complex number right? Then if
$$|z+1+3i|=0$$
$${\implies}|z|=|-1-3i|$$
In which sense does this
$$|z+1+3i|=|z-5-7i|$$
imply,
$$\implies|-4-4i|$$
But $z$ has vanished, which begs the question what is the point of including $z$ at all?

I know I'm getting something wrong, but what? Regards Tom

Comment: the notation should be interpreted as **magnitude**, not absolute value signs.

Comment: @VarunIyer: What does *magnitude* mean in this context?

Comment: If we let $z = a + bi$, then from the intepretation it follows that $\sqrt{(a+1)^2 + (b+3)^2} = \sqrt{(a-5)^2 + (b-7)^2}$

Comment: This says that the (Euclidean) distances in the complex plane between the points of affixes z and -1-3i on the one hand and z and 5+7i on the other hand, coincide. Once this geometric approach is mastered, it implies immediately that the set of solutions z is exactly the bisector of the segment with ends (-1,-3) and (5,7).

Comment: @Did is my solution incorrect then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to see with $\lvert z+1+3\mathrm i\rvert=0$. Geometrically, the equation means the image of $z$ is at the same distance from the image $A$ of $-1-3\mathrm i$ as from the image $B$ of $5+7\mathrm i$.

The locus of such points is the midperpendicular of $[AB]$; the midpoint of  $[AB]$ is the point with affix $\frac12(4+4\mathrm i)$.

Now the line $(AB)$ is directed by the vector $(3,5)$, hence perpendicular is directed by the vector $(-5,3)$, with affix $-5+3\mathrm i$. A point of the midperpendicular is $(2,2)+t(-5,3)(2-5t,2+3t),\enspace t\in\mathbf R$. 
Thus the solutions are:
$$z=2-5t+(2+3t)\mathrm i.$$

Comment: The choice of notation $\lvert-1-3\mathrm i\rvert$ and $\lvert 5+7\mathrm i\rvert$ is (unusual and quite) unfortunate.

Comment: 'Tis a typo. Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score -1):

The notation should be interpreted as magnitude, not absolute value signs.

If we let $z$, the complex number, be represented as $z = a + bi$, we can then say that:

$$\left|a+1 + i(b+ 3)\right| = \sqrt{(a+1)^2 + (b+3)^2}$$

and that:

$$\left|a-5 + i(b-7)\right| = \sqrt{(a-5)^2 + (b-7)^2}$$

Setting them equal to one another, we get that:

$$\sqrt{(a+1)^2 + (b+3)^2} = \sqrt{(a-5)^2 + (b-7)^2}$$

$$(a+1)^2 + (b+3)^2 = (a-5)^2 + (b-7)^2 $$

$$a^2 + 2a + 1 + b^2 + 6b + 9 = a^2 - 10a + 25 + b^2 -14b + 49$$

$$12a + 20b = 64,\ 3a + 5b = 16$$

One  possible solution is $a = -3$, $b = 5$. You can derive a set of solutions that satisfy this condition using the Euclidean Algorithm.

Therefore, $z$ can be: $z = -3 + 5i$

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "the notation should be interpreted as magnitude, not absolute value signs"? By  [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Complex_numbers) the absolute value of a complex number $x + iy$ is exactly $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$...

Comment: @A.P. I simply took the magnitude of both sides and eliminated the variables that were present on both sides of the equation. My first line was meant for the OP, because he simply "removed" the absolute value signs and performed subtraction, which isn't what you should do in this case.

Comment: @A.P. Those weren't $2$ linear equations. Sorry if they weren't clear. It is only one linear equation, and the second one next to it the same equation by instead all the terms were divided by $4$. Again, sorry it that wasn't clear.

Comment: To make my comment more clear: what are your *definitions* of magnitude and absolute value of a complex number? Your first line implies that they are different concepts, but from the rest of your answer they look the same to me. (I am totally with you on not liberally dropping the absolute value sign, but that's different)